# Comm usage and Subejct help!

Tags: punctuation, subjects

I am not an English expert. I need to know if I get the comma usage correct or not.

> John usually gets up before 7 o'clock, but yesterday his alarm clock did not ring, so he was still asleep when his boss called him at 10.30 to ask where he was and tell him that he would lose his job if he was late again.

The problem is, should I use comma before "and tell him that he would lose his job if he was late again."?

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: @AndrewLeach My second question is related to my first. If I get my answer for the second question I will also get answer for my first question.

Comment: Actually, you won't: it will need two distinct answers (which is exactly what's happened). Asking more than one question at once is not the way Stack Exchange works

Comment: Should I delete this??

Comment: It's good to keep this question open so that more people can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

1) The comma is not necessary. When a series of phrases is strung together with commas, the use of a comma before the "and" which ends the sentence not always required. In this case, especially, the phrase "to ask where he was and tell him that..." is a run-on version of "to ask where he was and **to** tell him that...".

2) By the same token, the last part of the sentence can be paraphrased as "the boss called to ask where he was, and also to tell him that...". It is clear that neither "ask" nor "tell" is an imperative.